# Open deep link url when clicking on FCB notification for both iOS and Android

Tags: react-native, firebase-cloud-messaging, react-native-firebase

I have a react-native app using [react-native-firebase-messaging](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@react-native-firebase/messaging) to send push notifications to android and iOS devices. I'm trying to embed a deep link in the [FCM message](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/java/reference/com/google/firebase/messaging/Message.Builder) so that users clicking on the notification will be routed to a specific section of the app. I've seen this [SO post](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/java/reference/com/google/firebase/messaging/Message.Builder) which shows how the `link` property can be added but it's specific to android. How can I add a deep link url to notifications sent to both iOS and Android devices?

Answer (score 1):

Without having deep link you can use notification click handler of react-native-firebase-messaging and pass the data in the notification payload which screen you want to navigate.

Check [this link](https://rnfirebase.io/messaging/notifications#handling-interaction) for documentation and make sure you have register background handler in index.js as [shown here](https://rnfirebase.io/messaging/usage#background--quit-state-messages)

```
useEffect(() => {
    // Assume a message-notification contains a "type" property in the data payload of the screen to open

    messaging().onNotificationOpenedApp(remoteMessage => {
        console.log(
        'Notification caused app to open from background state:',
        remoteMessage.notification,
        );
        navigation.navigate(remoteMessage.data.type);
    });

    // Check whether an initial notification is available
    messaging()
        .getInitialNotification()
        .then(remoteMessage => {
        if (remoteMessage) {
            console.log(
            'Notification caused app to open from quit state:',
            remoteMessage.notification,
            );
            setInitialRoute(remoteMessage.data.type); // e.g. "Settings"
        }
        setLoading(false);
        });
}, []);
```